# Python - calling a function that is in the parent file from imported file

Tags: python, python-import

As a part of a project I am working on in school, I have a main file (SM.py) and a folder called "mods" in which  you can put other .py files, which are imported into my program and add stuff to it (I don't want to start explaining what I am actually doing since it would take a long time, but if it's relevant I can explain it).

What I want to do is have a timer running inside one of my mod files, which calls a function called call_trigger(trigger) from the main file (SM.py). The problem is, I can't import the main file into the mod file since that would create circular dependency. So what I'm basically trying to do is:

a.py imports b.py, and a.py has a foo() function.
I want to call foo() from b.py without importing a.py first.

Hopefully I explained myself well, if you need further explaination I can provide it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback to achieve this:

```
# Some code from your top level
def foo():
    print("Foobar")

def bar(param):
    print("param=%s" % param)

# Code in the module
def baz(callback):
    print("Do something")
    callback()

baz(foo) # notice that there are no () after foo
baz(lambda: bar(23)) # lambda creates an anonymous function,
                     # which is called by baz. The call within
                     # baz is the point when bar(23) will be executed.
```

You can pass any callable object as a parameter to a python function, and can later call this parameter.